# QTextTable - create a table in a cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtextdocument

I have created a table using `QTextTable`.
Here is my code:

```
QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
tableFormat.setBackground(QColor(Qt::white));
//tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
tableFormat.setCellSpacing(0);
tableFormat.setTopMargin(0);
tableFormat.setCellPadding(40);

QTextTableFormat childtableformat;
childtableformat.setCellSpacing(0);
childtableformat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignBaseline); 
tableFormat.setWidth(QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 100));
tableFormat.setCellPadding(10);
cursor.insertText("table below ");
QTextTable* table=cursor.insertTable(3,3,tableFormat);
 cursor = table->cellAt(0, 0).firstCursorPosition();
 QTextTable* childtable=cursor.insertTable(2,2,tableFormat);
textEdit->show();
```

New table which I have created is appending in the center of the cell which is looking awkward. Is there any way to fit the child table to the parent cell?
I tried to change QTextTableFormat but nothing worked.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518211/how-to-change-row-height-in-qtexttable

Comment: You example is uncomplete, missing how you initialize cursor